# What is wrong with my shell script's if condition?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a secondary list of start up programs that I would like to start in case I am working. So I have added this shell script to the start up of my system running on Ubuntu.

```
echo "Do you want to start the start up applications[Y/n]?"

while read inputline
do
    what="$inputline"
    break
done

if [ "$what" == "Y" -o "$what" == "y" ]
then
. ~/bin/webstorm.sh &
workrave &
firefox &
. ~/bin/AptanaStudio3
fi
```

I keep getting this error that says something like `[: Y: unexpected operator` all the time and never starts the programs.

**Disclaimer: I have no idea how to write shell scripts.**

Comment: Single `=` vs double `==`?  At least worth a try...  I don't understand your read loop compared to `read what`; when would your loop behave differently?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: I guess the intent is to give the user an opportunity to cancel at the prompt. Of course just a `read` without a `while` loop would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if [ "$what" == "Y" -o "$what" == "y" ]
```

to

```
if [[ "$what" == "Y" ]] || [[ "$what" == "y" ]]
```

Comment: Or better yet `case $what in [Yy] ) ;; * ) exit 0 ;; esac`

Answer (score 0):

What is your shebang line? `#!/bin/bash` or  `#!/bin/sh`?

If you are intending to use bash as script interpreter, don't forget shebang line.

(Your code is working with bash on my system at least..)

Comment: For `sh` you'd need to change `~` to `$HOME` too.

Comment: Hmm... I did not check upto that. since the condition statement itself was failing.